# Android: how to check the location is current location or last known location

Tags: android, location

In my app I getting location from network and if network is not not available my code returns the last location, In both the cases I want to know whether the location is current location or it is the last known location. can somebody please show me how to know this.Thanks in advance

```
 public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }

           else{ }   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }      
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
      return longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to achieve this using [SharedPrefences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Store the current location(the latitude and longitude upto approx 5 decimal places)  in shared preferences.Compare the new location with that in the shared preferences.If they are same,then the new location is your last known location,if not the new location is the new one,save it again in your shared preference.